# Convert Stem and Leaf to a Vector in R Efficiently

Tags: r, performance, type-conversion

I need to verify summary statistics (mean, standard deviation etc.) for many stem and leaf plots so I have written some functions to try and convert a stem and leaf plot into a vector since it is easy to obtain statistics from vectors in R.

A stem and leaf plot can be entered as a matrix or a data frame where each row is a string. The "|" symbol represents the separator for a decimal place. For example, the stem and leaf plot below

```
100 | 9
102 | 601
104 | 0678
106 | 5
108 | 649
110 | 3857
112 | 56
114 | 29
```

can be entered as

```
> example.stem = rbind("100|9", "102|601", "104|0678", "106|5", "108|649", "110|3857", "112|56", "114|29")
```

My two functions that perform the conversion of this stem and leaf plot are

```
## Convert a single row into a vector
> convert.row = function(current){

  temp.split = as.vector(strsplit(current, split="|", fixed=TRUE)[[1]])

  int = temp.split[1]

  dec = temp.split[2]
  dec = (strsplit(dec, ""))[[1]]

  temp.string = NULL

  for(i in 1:length(dec)){
    temp.string[i] = paste(int, dec[i], sep=".")
  }

  result = as.numeric(temp.string)
  return(result)
  }


## Convert matrix or dataframe with a stem and leaf plot into a vector
> stem.to.vec = function(df){  

  df = data.frame(df, stringsAsFactors = F)  

  result.vec = NULL

  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    current = df[i, ]
    result.vec = c(result.vec, convert.row(current))
  }

  return(result.vec)
  }
```

We can verify this works because we know the solution:

```
> solution = c(100.9, 102.6,102.0,102.1,104.0,104.6,104.7,104.8,106.5,108.6,108.4,108.9,110.3,110.8,110.5,110.7,112.5,112.6, 114.2, 114.9)
> stem.to.vec(example.stem) == solution
```

Although this solution works, it is not elegant or efficient. We are converting a matrix/data frame with strings into a numeric value, then back to a string and then into a numeric value again. Therefore it can be slow to work for very large stem and leaf plots.

Can anyone suggest a better and more efficient solution with fewer conversions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is far from pretty, but I think you're going to have to do some back and forth conversion anyway.

Use `read.table` to suck the data in, then divide the right hand side by 10 and add to each value on the left side.

```
out <- read.table(text=example.stem, sep="|", colClasses=c("numeric","character"))
res <- unlist(Map(`+`, out$V1, lapply(strsplit(out$V2,""), function(x) as.numeric(x)/10)))
res
# [1] 100.9 102.6 102.0 102.1 104.0 104.6 104.7 104.8 106.5 108.6 108.4 108.9
# [13] 110.3 110.8 110.5 110.7 112.5 112.6 114.2 114.9

identical(solution,res)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

**Split and paste approach:**

Split into list items and then split the second element of list items. Finally paste the two vectors in a list item.

```
x <- sapply(strsplit(example.stem, "[|]"), 
            function(x) { paste(x[1], unlist(strsplit(x[2], "")), sep= ".") })

as.numeric(unlist(x))                           

# [1] 100.9 102.6 102.0 102.1 104.0 104.6 104.7 104.8 106.5 108.6 108.4 108.9 
# [13] 110.3 110.8 110.5 110.7 112.5 112.6 114.2 114.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a nested `lapply` version that does all the combining as strings, then converts the output value to numeric:

```
out <- unlist(lapply(strsplit(example.stem, "[|]"), function(x){
  lapply(x[2], function(y){
    as.numeric(paste(x[1], unlist(strsplit(y, "")), sep = "."))
  })
}))

> identical(solution, out)
[1] TRUE
```